# No able to reinitialize the WCHAR[] array once it gets the initialized

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, widechar

```
While(1)
{
WCHAR wcImageName[80];
if ( pxmlNameTag->GetData(wcImageName, wcslen(wcImageName)) )
{
    if ( !wcscmp(wcImageName, String2) )
       {
           Printf("String matched");
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           Printf("In else");
       }
 }
 else
 {
       Printf("Failed to get the data");
 }
}
}
```

I am iterating the loop till i got the matching string. GetData is used to get the string into wcImageName. 1st time a am able to get the data into wcImageName and it is compared with string2. If not matched loop iterate 2nd time. i am declaring wcImageName again but GetData is not able to copy the data into wcImageName. because it is initialized. i have tried to initialize it with L'\0' but the same result.

Comment: What are `While`, `WCHAR` and `Printf`? Are they visual studio specific identifiers, or are they your definitions that are missing form the example? The definition of `String2` variable is missing as well.

Comment: Can you show the pxmlNameTag->GetData code?

Comment: Have you tried with `WCHAR wcImageName[80] {};` ?

Comment: On the very first iteration, you are calling `wcslen` on random uninitialized garbage. Your program exhibits undefined behavior right there. You likely meant `_countof(wcImageName)`

Comment: You also have more closing braces than opening ones.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik : Your solution worked for me, thanks for help. wcslen returning 0, that's why the GetData() fails every time. So i have changed it to countof() and it worked for me.